# Tschirnhausen cubic - expressing in terms of x

Tags: cubics

Is there a way to express the following function $$y=x\sqrt{x+3}$$ in the form $x$ as a function of $y$?

Thanks

Comment: @dragon Clarified my post.

Comment: If $\alpha = \frac{1}{4}(4 y + 4 \sqrt{y^2 - 4})^{2 / 3}$, then $x = \alpha + 1 + \frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Square both sides, and use the [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) to extract *x* as a function of *y*. Of course, this might introduce some extra solutions. Notice that $x\ge-3$.